# How to apply CSS on only the first page of PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I've a page which is built using Vue.js + vuetify + nuxt.js.

The page is getting printed using a backend PDF generation solution, (it's using puppeteer)
How can apply some specific CSS on only the first page of the PDF, basically it's a fixed header which should have the same style on all of the PDF pages except the header.

I tried

```
@page :first { 
...
}
```

But I can only use limited set of CSS features

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

Any javascript or CSS related solution for this?

Comment: _"basically it's a fixed header which has the same style on all of the PDF pages except the header."_ - huh? Did you mean "except on the first page"? Or do you want the fixed header to only show on the first page, and not at all any more on the rest?

Comment: Well I made an edit, bascially the fixed header should have the same style on all the PDF pages except the first page. @CBroe

Comment: what, in CSS terms, is the difference on the first page

Comment: The fixed header of the page should only contain some specific message and on the other pages the header should contain some other message.

Comment: I am not sure that is actually achievable. I am guessing using puppeteer means, this is actually just loading the page in a headless browser, and then uses that one's print functionality, yes? Browsers print fixed elements onto every page, and `@page` only allows you to specify properties _for_ the page, it does not allow for usage in any kind of descendant selector to select any elements "in" a page. [...]

Comment: [...] The only possible workaround I see here is to have an extra header that is _not_ fixed (so that it will print only on the first page), and to try and make it cover up the fixed header that will print onto every page including the first one. So you would need a solid background for that first page header (and the browser printing this to a PDF would need to be set to print backgrounds/background colors to begin with), and it would have to have at least the same size as the fixed one.